# Electron Forge with SASS

Tags: css, sass, electron, electron-forge

I use Electron Forge for an Electron app. I also make use of React and TypeScript, and I would also like to use SASS, but my current attempts fail.  Apparently SASS already works without adding any new dependency to the `package.json`, as `electron-compile` takes care of that. That's what it sais on [electronforge.io](https://electronforge.io/) under *Develop*.

I tried adding the `style.scss` as an import within the first TypeScript class `app.tsx`, but after adding this compiling does not work anymore:

```
import "./style/style.scss";
```

leads to:

```
[24717:0221/194746.779571:ERROR:CONSOLE(7830)] "Extension server error: Object not found: <top>", source: chrome-devtools://devtools/bundled/shell.js (7830)
```

I also tried to put a `link` element into the `head` element in the `index.html`, but this does not do the trick either. Compiling works, but no CSS works are done:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style/style.scss">
```

also tried:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/style.scss">
```

and:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/scss" href="style/style.scss">
```

and:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/sass" href="style/style.scss">
```

The 'style.scss` file:

```
body {
    background-color: #ff0000;
    color: #0000ff;
}
```

But none of them work. What must I do to make use of SASS files within Electron Forge?

Answer (score 6):

I've managed to get this working, little bit late but hopefully this helps someone in the future. On an example app using webpack (as I'm pretty sure this is required), Electron Forge generates some js files in the root directory for webpack config.

```
yarn create electron-app my-new-app --template=webpack
```

or

```
yarn create electron-app my-new-app --template=typescript,webpack
```

https://www.electronforge.io/templates/typescript-+-webpack-template

Following this, there's two files in the project root, `webpack.rules.js` and `webpack.plugins.main.config.js`. These need to be modified to work properly, and you need to install `sass-loader` as a dev dependency. `node-sass` was recently deprecated so `sass-loader` will handle that okay.

Your `webpack.plugins.main.config.js` file should include:

```
module: {
  rules: require("./webpack.rules"),
},
resolve: {
  extensions: [
    ".js",
    ".ts",
    ".jsx",
    ".tsx",
    ".css",
    ".json",
    ".scss",
    ".sass",
  ],
},
```

Additionally, your `webpack.rules.js` file should have a new rule added:

```
{
  test: /\.s[ac]ss$/i,
  use: [
    // Creates `style` nodes from JS strings
    "style-loader",
    // Translates CSS into CommonJS
    "css-loader",
    // Compiles Sass to CSS
    "sass-loader",
  ],
},
```

This is what's provided in the documentation on the page for `sass-loader`, properly implemented into electron forge. https://www.npmjs.com/package/sass-loader

Finally, your renderer.js (or renderer.js) should be adapted to import a scss file rather than a css file.

```
import './index.scss';
```

From there, you should be good to go!

Comment: Following this method, I get an error when I try to compile: `SassError: expected "{".` referring to `import API from "!../../node_modules/style-loader/dist/runtime/injectStylesIntoStyleTag.js";`.

Comment: I see the same behavior as @SimpleProgrammer

Answer (score 2):

You need to compile the `SASS` file to generate a `CSS` file and then put it in the index.html
Yo can use the console to try it

```
# Path to SASS File > OUTPUT path to CSS File
sass style/sass/style.scss style/style.css
```

then, import the file in the head

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style/style.css">
```

Comment: Ok, this works, but it is not very pretty as I have to do this by hand every time before I `yarn start` the app.

Comment: use the flag `-w`  `sass style/sass/style.scss style/style.css -w` this command makes the file constant watched

Comment: Ok, this might do as a workaround. Although it requires opening two terminals. One for `npx sass --watch --no-source-map src/style/style.scss src/style/style.css` and a second one for `yarn start`.

Comment: Also, with this method Electron Forge does not track either the CSS or the SCSS. Hence, when changed there is not automatic reload.

Comment: Electron does not current implementing SASS :/ [look this](https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-compile/issues/162)

Comment: SASS works without problems in Electron when using Webpack. DevDependencies: `node-sass` and `sass-loader`. Within `webpack.config.js` add `sass-loader` as a module rule. But here I am trying to use SASS within *Electron Forge* where there is no access to any Webpack configuration.